# Store statistics with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-aop

I have AOP aspect for counting times some service was called:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class CounterAspect {

    private Map<Integer, Integer> gettingEventStatistics = new HashMap<>();

    @Pointcut("execution(Event EventService+.getById(Integer))")
    private void gettingEvent() {}

    @AfterReturning(pointcut = "gettingEvent()", returning = "retVal")
    public void countGettingEvent(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object retVal) {
        Integer id = (Integer) joinPoint.getArgs()[0];
        if (id != null && retVal != null) {
            Integer currentCounterValue = gettingEventStatistics.get(id);
            gettingEventStatistics.put(id, currentCounterValue == null ? 1 : currentCounterValue + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

How could I store such an information in DB using Hibernate?

Comment: what's stopping you from autowiring repository related beans and persisting data manually in a table of your choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made the following solution - created entity for stats

```
@Entity
public class GettingEventsStats {
    @Id
    private Integer eventId;
    private Integer gettingCounter;
//getters, setters, etc.
```

injected DAO delegate in my aspect with such a functionality:

```
@Repository
public class HibernateStatsDao implements StatsDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public GettingEventsStats getGettingEventStats(Integer eventId) {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(GettingEventsStats.class, eventId);
    }

    @Override
    public void createGettingEventCounter(Integer eventId) {
        GettingEventsStats gettingEventsStats = new GettingEventsStats();
        gettingEventsStats.setEventId(eventId);
        gettingEventsStats.setGettingCounter(1);
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(gettingEventsStats);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateGettingEventCounter(Integer eventId) {
        GettingEventsStats gettingEventStats = getGettingEventStats(eventId);
        gettingEventStats.setGettingCounter(gettingEventStats.getGettingCounter() + 1);
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(gettingEventStats);
    }
}
```

and changed aspect logic to:

```
@Autowired
private StatsDao statsDao;

@Pointcut("execution(Event EventService+.getById(Integer))")
private void gettingEvent() {}

@AfterReturning(pointcut = "gettingEvent()", returning = "retVal")
public void countGettingEvent(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object retVal) {
    Integer eventId = (Integer) joinPoint.getArgs()[0];
    if (eventId != null && retVal != null) {
        GettingEventsStats gettingEventStats = statsDao.getGettingEventStats(eventId);
        if (gettingEventStats == null) {
            statsDao.createGettingEventCounter(eventId);
        } else {
            statsDao.updateGettingEventCounter(eventId);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be parse it to JSON and store as a string. Remember then to increase column max memory size.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to save a lot of entries with this method. Better use D[ropwizard Metrics](https://dropwizard.github.io/metrics/3.1.0/) which uses Reservoirs for data sampling and custom reporters.

Typically, the metrics are better off exposed through JMX to an APM tool. Or you should use Graphite or Graphana for this purpose.

Comment: I had a study project with the task to use Hibernate for persistance, but thanks - I will try suggested tool.